# Django Attribute Error - object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: django, inline-formset

I am trying to create a multiple file upload form using inlineformset factory. I followed the process defined in https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#django.forms.models.BaseInlineFormSet.

I am getting following errow.

Attached the views.py and model.py file.

please help.

```
Error:
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/tagging/UploadMultipleFile/1/
Django Version: 3.0.2
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:    
'UploadMultiFile' object has no attribute 'get'
Exception Location: 
Python Version: 3.8.1
```

```
#MODELS.PY
class UploadInputFile(models.Model):
    process=models.ForeignKey(Process,blank=False,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name="inputfile")
    inputfilepath=models.FileField(upload_to=user_directory_path, null=True)
    inputfilename=models.CharField(max_length=300,blank=True)
    multiplefile=models.BooleanField(blank=True,default=False)
    date_uploaded = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return(self.process.process_name)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("tagging:tagginghome")

class UploadMultiFile(models.Model):
    process=models.ForeignKey(Process,blank=False,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name="process")
    batch=models.ForeignKey(UploadInputFile,blank=False,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name="multiplefiles")
    inputfilepath=models.FileField(upload_to=user_directory_path, null=True)
    inputfilename=models.CharField(max_length=300,blank=True)
    date_uploaded = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return(self.batch_id.process_id.process_name)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("tagging:tagginghome")
```

```
# VIEWS.PY 
# upload Multiple files
def UploadMultipleFile(request,batchid):
    batchid=int(batchid)
    pk=batchid
    getProcessAndBatch=UploadInputFile.objects.all().values().get(id=batchid)
    MultiFileUploadFormSet = inlineformset_factory(UploadInputFile,UploadMultiFile,fk_name='batch',fields=('inputfilepath','inputfilename'))
    if request.method=="POST":
        formset= MultiFileUploadFormSet(request.POST,request.FILES,instance=getProcessAndBatch)
        if formset.is_valid():
            formset.save()
    else:
        formset= MultiFileUploadFormSet(instance=getProcessAndBatch)

    return render(request,"tagging/UploadInputFile_Form.html",{'pk':pk,'formset':formset})
```

Comment: You may want to clarify your question. What are you trying to do? What have you tried to do? You gave your code and the error message, which is good, but since the error message is pretty explicit, it's rather hard to guess what you don't understand.

Comment: Thanks Ryan. I have resolved this issue. it was a simple spell mistake in URL.